# Trying to understand Await/Async, is this a correct conversion?

Tags: node.js, async-await

So I am trying to rewrite the following callback function using the async/await pattern in node 8.9.4.  Do I have it right or should it be rewritten further?

```
const fs = require("fs");

const makeBackup = (file, callback) => {
    if(fs.existsSync(`${file}.bak`)) return callback(null, true);
    fs.copyFile(file, `${file}.bak`, cpErr => {
        if(cpErr && cpErr.code === "ENOENT"){
            fs.writeFile(`${file}.bak`, Buffer.alloc(0), writeErr => {
                if(writeErr) return callback(writeErr);
                return callback(null, true);
            });
        } else if(cpErr) return callback(cpErr);
        return callback(null, true);
    })
}
```

Here is the async/await function I have come up with.

```
import fs, { copyFile, writeFile } from "fs";
import { promisify } from "util";

const makeBackup = async file => {
  // if backup file exists already do nothing further return true.
  if (fs.existsSync(`${file}.bak`)) return true;
  try {
    copyFile = promisify(fs.copyFile);
    // if backup file doens't exist copy file to file.bak
    await copyFile(file, `${file}.bak`);
    // return true when file is copied to bakup file.
    return true;
  } catch (cpErr) {
    // if file missing create an empty backup file
    if (cpErr.code === "ENOENT") {
      try {
        writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);
        await writeFile(`${file}.bak`, Buffer.alloc(0));
        return true;
      } catch (writeErr) {
        // if error writing to file for any reason return error
        return writeErr;
      }
    }
    // if copy error for any other reason return error
    return cpErr;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would break it into two functions. It's easier to read, and there is less of try/catch.

My own rule is when I see nested try/catch or nested Array functions it means that you have to create separated functions.

```
     async makeBackup(file) {
        // if backup file exists already do nothing further return true.
        if (fs.existsSync(`${file}.bak`)) return true;

        try {
          copyFile = promisify(fs.copyFile);

          // if backup file doens't exist copy file to file.bak
          await copyFile(file, `${file}.bak`);

          // return true when file is copied to bakup file.
          return true;
        } catch (cpErr) {
          // if file missing create an empty backup file
          if (cpErr && cpErr.code === "ENOENT") {
            return createEmptyBackupFile(file);
          }

          // if copy error for any other reason return error
          return cpErr;
        }
     }

     async createEmptyBackupFile(file) {
        writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);

        // if error writing to file for any reason it will throw an error
        await writeFile(`${file}.bak`, Buffer.alloc(0));

        return true;
     }
```

Comment: Even though you return a hard true in CreateEmptyBackupFile it will still return with an error if the write errors out?

Comment: When an error happens into an Promise ,the error is throwed. It means that any code between where the error is throwed and where the error is catched is not gonna be executed. In this case the error gonna be throwed inside of writeFile. Because there is no catch into createEmptyBackFile, the error gonna be throwed in the calling function (makeBackup). Then because there is no try/catch surrounding the createEmptyBackupFile call in makeBackup, makeBackup gonna be throwed in the calling function (...) ..etc until it reach a try/catch

Comment: [Here](https://javascript.info/async-await) is a tutorial about async/await. There is a section error handling, you should look about it